# How do I create a proportional bar chart in R per columns of a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (`df`) structured as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(header1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("bad", 
"good", "so-so"), class = "factor"), header2 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("bad", "good"), class = "factor"), header3 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("bad", "good", "so-so"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I've been trying to use `plot_stackfrq` from the `sjPlot` package to produce a proportional bar chart.  Note that the `header2` column is missing any 'so-so' values (only header1 and header3 have `so-so` values). I've tried, but the colors in the resulting proportional bars are not displayed correctly. The color corresponding to `so-so`  in `header1` and `header3` is presented as the color corresponding to `good` in columns 'header2'.

Does anyone have a solution for this using `sjPlot` or any other R library that can create a proportionate bar chart for each column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what problem it is giving you. I managed to produce the following plot which is a representative to the data in your sample `df`.

```
library(sjPlot)

# get the index of columns to plot

start <- which(colnames(df)=="header1")

end <- which(colnames(df)=="header3")

plot_stackfrq(df[, start:end])

#If you want to set colors manually 
# plot_stackfrq(df[, start:end], geom.colors = c("#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#0072B2"))
# Assign colors in alphabetical order bad -> good -> so-so.
```

## Data

```r
df <- structure(list(header1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("bad", 
"good", "so-so"), class = "factor"), header2 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("bad", "good"), class = "factor"), header3 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("bad", "good", "so-so"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

## Output

[image: sjPlot]

Comment: I was able to regenerate this exact solution on my end but I don't get the same result with my actual dataset.  Is there something particular you are doing with your data frame to construct this?

Comment: I figured it out, I was treating the items in each column as strings, not factors.  When I converted the strings to factors, the code in this example worked perfectly.